# When converting .py to .exe it doesen't find a library anymore

Tags: python, keyboard, pyinstaller

i have been working on a python project and i am finally done, i used pyinstaller to convert the .py file to an exe but whe i try to run the exe it gives me a 'Module not found' error for the keyboard module.

I tried to install again the keyboard module and it still doesen't work, i have no idea what happened.
The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

when running it in pycharm it works flawlessly. the only attribute i used when converting was `--noconsole`

Comment: create a [mre].